# Connecting points with ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm looking for a way to connect some points using ggplot in R.  I want to connect each point to the nearest point.  Here's what my data look like as a scatter plot.

```
x <- c(0.81,0.82,0.82,0.82,0.83,0.83,0.83,0.84,0.84,0.84,0.85,0.85,0.85,0.86,0.86,0.86,0.87,0.87,0.87,0.88,0.88,0.88,0.89,0.89,0.89,0.9,0.9,0.9,0.91,0.91,0.91,0.92,0.92,0.92,0.93,0.93,0.93,0.93,0.93,0.94,0.94,0.94,0.94,0.94,0.95,0.95,0.95,0.95,0.95,0.96,0.96,0.96,0.96,0.96,0.97,0.97,0.97,0.97,0.97,0.98,0.98,0.98,0.98,0.98,0.99,0.99,0.99,0.99,1,1,1,1,1.01,1.01,1.01,1.01,1.02,1.02,1.02,1.02,1.03,1.03,1.03,1.03,1.04,1.04,1.04,1.04,1.05,1.05,1.05,1.05,1.06,1.06,1.06,1.06,1.07,1.07,1.07,1.07,1.08,1.08,1.08,1.08,1.09,1.09,1.09,1.09,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.1,1.11,1.11,1.11,1.11,1.12,1.12,1.12,1.12,1.13,1.13,1.13,1.13,1.14,1.14,1.15,1.15,1.16,1.16,1.17,1.17,1.18,1.18,1.19,1.19,1.2,1.2,1.21,1.21,1.22,1.22,1.23,1.23,1.24,1.24,1.25,1.25,1.26,1.26,1.27)

y <- c(-1.295,-0.535,-1.575,-1.295,-0.525,-1.575,-1.295,-0.515,-1.575,-1.285,-0.515,-1.575,-1.285,-0.505,-1.575,-1.275,-0.495,-1.575,-1.275,-0.485,-1.575,-1.265,-0.485,-1.575,-1.265,-0.475,-1.575,-1.255,-0.465,-1.575,-1.255,-0.455,-1.575,-1.245,-0.445,1.285,1.545,-1.575,-1.245,-0.435,1.165,1.675,-1.575,-1.235,-0.425,1.085,1.765,-1.575,-1.235,-0.405,1.015,1.845,-1.575,-1.225,-0.395,0.965,1.905,-1.575,-1.215,-0.385,0.915,1.965,-1.575,-1.215,-0.375,0.865,-1.575,-1.205,-0.355,0.825,-1.575,-1.205,-0.345,0.785,-1.565,-1.195,-0.325,0.745,-1.565,-1.185,-0.305,0.705,-1.565,-1.185,-0.285,0.665,-1.565,-1.175,-0.265,0.625,-1.565,-1.165,-0.245,0.585,-1.565,-1.165,-0.225,0.545,-1.565,-1.155,-0.195,0.495,-1.555,-1.145,-0.165,0.455,-1.555,-1.145,-0.135,0.405,-1.555,-1.135,-0.0849999999999999,0.345,-1.555,-1.125,-0.035,0.275,-1.545,-1.115,0.0850000000000001,0.145,-1.545,-1.115,-1.545,-1.105,-1.545,-1.095,-1.535,-1.085,-1.535,-1.085,-1.535,-1.075,-1.525,-1.065,-1.525,-1.055,-1.525,-1.045,-1.515,-1.045,-1.515,-1.035,-1.505,-1.025,-1.505,-1.015,-1.495,-1.005,-1.495)

example_df <- tibble(x = x, y = y)

ggplot(example_df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]

The default behavior of geom_line is to connect coordinates according to the order in which they appear in the dataframe.  Is there an easy way to connect points according to Euclidean distance between points?

Comment: In your full problem, will you have some way of marking which group a point belongs to, or is that part of the question? Like in this case there would be 3 groups because (I assume) you're expecting 3 paths through these points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another answer - that will work for this data, but not in general

```
example_df$group <- cut(example_df$y, 
                        breaks = c(Inf, -0.8, -1.4, -Inf))     #breaks determined 'by eye'
example_df <- example_df[order(example_df$y), ]                #sort by y
ggplot(example_df, aes(x = x, y = y, group = group)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_path(colour = "blue")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  This solves the issue as stated in the prompt. It would be nice to be able to connect points without having to group at splits on the y-axis.  This solution wouldn't work for cases where groups of points are not separable by a horizontal line.  Hopefully someone will develop a package to add this functionality to ggplot.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution to the question you asked, although I suspect it is not quite what you actually wanted, but it might help...

```
distmat <- as.matrix(dist(example_df))    #matrix of Euclidean distances between rows
diag(distmat) <- Inf                      #remove zeros on diagonal
nearest <- apply(distmat, 1, which.min)   #find index of nearest point to each point
example_df$xend <- example_df$x[nearest]  #set end point of segment from each point
example_df$yend <- example_df$y[nearest]

ggplot(example_df, aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(colour = "blue")
```

[image]

Comment: This helps but I'm looking to connect the all the points.  Ideally I'd like to use something like geom_path and a grouping variable.

Comment: Why are there gaps between some points? Looking at the code, I can't see why that would happen

Comment: @camille This just connects to the nearest point.  If A is the nearest to B and B is the nearest to A, then B will not connect to C, even though that might look like the visually sensible next step. For continuous lines along the three perceived series of dots, some of them would need to connect to the second nearest (or, conceivably, even further).  I think that is a non-trivial problem!

Comment: I think the solution may involve iteratively removing points from the set of candidate points at each step where a nearest point is selected.  For example, if B is chosen as the nearest point to A, then A should not be an option when finding a nearest point to B.

Comment: You're right that this may be a non-trivial problem!

Answer (score 1):

This differs from Andrew Gustar's [`cut`-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58259843/5325862) just in how to separate the 3 paths. I wanted it to be a little more of a scalable process, so I tried using hierarchical clustering to put the points into 3 clusters based on their distances between one another. In this case, they were easily separable; with other data, it might be more tricky and you might need different clustering algorithms. Then based on the other answer (+1 to them), arrange each cluster by y-value to get paths to draw in the right order.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

example_df <- tibble(x = x, y = y)
clust <- hclust(dist(example_df), method = "single")

df_clustered <- example_df %>%
  mutate(cluster = as.factor(cutree(clust, k = 3))) %>%
  arrange(cluster, y)

ggplot(df_clustered, aes(x = x, y = y, color = cluster)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_path()
```

[image]

Comment: Hadn't considered a clustering-based solution.  This is useful.